# How to move a div depending on scroll percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make some animations for my application but I can't figure it out. I want the text and description to move depending on how much of the page scrolls. For the first div I managed to do it, but for the others, nothing happens. How could I do that when I scroll more than 40% to move the div according to the scroll? 
[Here is my code](https://codepen.io/CosminAndrei2000/pen/LYYNXZd)

```js
 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        let height = $('body').height();
        let scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (scroll > height * 0.01) {
            $('.div1 .title').css({
                left: -350 + Math.min(350, scroll)
            });
            $('.div1 .description').css({
                left: -350 + Math.min(350, scroll)
            });
        }
        if (scroll > height * 0.4) {
            $('.div2 .title').css({
               right: -350 + Math.min(350, scroll)
            });
            $('.div2 .description').css({
                right: -350 + Math.min(350, scroll)
            });
        }

    });
```

```css
   body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .div1 {

        }
        .div1, .div2, .div3 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 500px;
        }

        .left {
            width: 500px;
        }

        .right {
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        .right img, .left img {
            width: 100%;
        }
       .div1 .title {
            position: relative;
            left: -350px;
        }
        .div1 .description {
            position: relative;
            left: -350px;
        }
        .div2 .title {
            position: relative;
            right: -350px;
        }
        .div2 .description {
            position: relative;
            right: -350px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam iste aliquid nihil
                mollitia, cum recusandae molestias quod veritatis amet odit officiis quo assumenda ullam fugiat est
                dolorum
                ea pariatur doloribus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam iste aliquid nihil
                mollitia, cum recusandae molestias quod veritatis amet odit officiis quo assumenda ullam fugiat est
                dolorum
                ea pariatur doloribus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="div3">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Some title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam iste aliquid nihil
                mollitia, cum recusandae molestias quod veritatis amet odit officiis quo assumenda ullam fugiat est
                dolorum
                ea pariatur doloribus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is with the following code: `right: -350 + Math.min(350, scroll)`. This seems to be always be zero since once the screen has scrolled more then 40%, chances are that 350 is the smaller value (`350 - 350 = 0`). Sorry, I don't have time to write out a full answer but hopefully that's a starting point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following function to move the title and desription in each divs depending on the scroll position:

```
 function moveOnViewPort(el, mult) {
    let scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  let viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
  let elementScrollPos = $(el).offset().top;

  if((scrollPos + viewPortHeight) >  elementScrollPos) {
    let moveVal = (scrollPos + viewPortHeight - elementScrollPos) * mult;
    if($(el).hasClass('move-left')) {
        $(el).find('.move').css({
                left: -350 + Math.min(350, moveVal)
            });
    }
    else if($(el).hasClass('move-right')) {
        $(el).find('.move').css({
                right: -350 + Math.min(350, moveVal)
            });
    }
  }
 }
```

Working demo and implementation details can you find here: https://jsfiddle.net/dat57qse/

Comment: Mostly that's what I want, but I have more titles and descriptions that do not reach the same left and right. For example, I have a title that starts from left: -450px and that reaches left: 150px, and the description starts from left: -350px and reaches left: 80px. How could I do that I could avoid the method of writing for each one another left and right?

Comment: I made a new working demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/gmy1uc2p/

I modified the move methode so that it moves titles and descriptions independently. I defined different extra-classes for the title, description moving types. For example 'title-type-1' or 'title-type-2' . The extra-class will define which move start, move end values should be applied on the actual title Each title type has an extra speed multiplier, that influence the move speed, because a title which move from -450 to 150px should move faster as a title from -350 to 80.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to move the first title and first description when I start scrolling? I ask because on a resolution of 2560x1440 you can already see the title and the description and the animation does not happen anymore. For the rest it is good because you can not see when the page is loading. I have attached a link to the video : https://files.fm/u/wft4auvs

Comment: The problem is, that the move function is called first time on scroll, so the first element jumps when the scrolling starts. We have to init the move position of each element on load, before the scrolling start, so can we eliminate this jump effect. Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bcwyta5m/2/
Please give me a positive vote if my answer was helpful.

Comment: The start position of the first title and description will be pretty close to the end position, it is because the first component is already on the page. It is normal. You should insert an header image, or something above the first component. Please give me a positive vote if it was helpful. Thanks!