# How would I transform a divs position depending on users scroll with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to make something similar to [How to move a div depending on scroll percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395212/how-to-move-a-div-depending-on-scroll-percentage) for a single div.

However, I do not want the function to have an Event Listener for the entire page, I want the div to start transforming its position depending on user scroll once the div comes into the users viewport, similar to this website https://www.fhoke.com/ (middle of website)

I do not want to use JQuery, only pure JavaScript.

How would I make an iteration counter to make the movement of the div smooth correlating to user scroll?
Should I have a JS function iterate a call to a CSS class?
And should I use an Intersection Observer to toggle the movement function on/off?

Would I be on the right track with my logic below? If I am, how would I create this?

```
Intersection Observer (check if user is intersecting container which has the div which moves in it)
Height of Page & Height of Viewport (to calculate scroll speed/amount)

if intersecting => 
   Movement function
     check if user is scrolling up/down
       if user scroll down =>
        move div RTL X amount depending on scroll amount
       else user scroll up =>
        move div LTR X amount depending on scroll amount
not intersecting =>
   Deactivate function
```

Comment: Have a go at coding it in JS and show us the result if you get stuck. Personally I would use an IntersectionObserver to tell me when a section comes into and out of the viewport as that is easy and saves having to look every time the user scrolls outside the section, but there's probably no 'should' about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short exemple that you can edit at the way you want.

The code bellow will give you some clues.

You can now listen the **window scroll** and move an element using **transform**.

Then apply the condition you want and adapt the code as you wish :)

```js
// Source credit: http://thenewcode.com/279/Rotate-Elements-on-Scroll-with-JavaScript
var item = document.getElementById('item')
var item1 = document.getElementById('item1')
;(function(){
  var throttle = function(type, name, obj){
    var obj = obj || window;
    var running = false;
    var func = function(){
      if (running){ return; }
      running = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
        running = false;
      });
    };
    obj.addEventListener(type, func);
  };
  
  throttle("scroll", "optimizedScroll");
})();

window.addEventListener("optimizedScroll", function(){
  item.style.transform = "translate( 0px," + window.pageYOffset * 10 + "%)";
 item1.style.transform = "translate( 0px," + window.pageYOffset * 5 + "%)";
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  }
  
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div id="item" class="item"></div>
  <div id="item1" class="item"></div>
  <div id="item2" class="item"></div>
```